# Django-paypal Heroku VS Local ? PAYPAL IPN

Tags: django, heroku, paypal, paypal-ipn, django-paypal

In my development locally the django-paypal plugin is amazing and have had ZERO issues attempting paypal and the developer account.  After pushing to heroku, i cant seem to contact the paypal server doing the exact same steps....

for example when in local development i am getting the Payment Accepted and the IPN to return to my localhost with ngrok.

once i pushed the app to heroku everything loaded and it was looking good, my problem is not i am getting a 500 error from paypal when attempting to connect to the sandbox in from heroku??

Please help, 
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

This took me FOREVER so im posting this here for the next up and comming django dev looking to work with the django-by-example book and using heroku as a production host!

```
heroku addons:add cloudamqp
Adding cloudamqp on secure-fortress-6930... done, v6 (free)
Use `heroku addons:docs cloudamqp` to view documentation.

BROKER_URL = os.environ.get("CLOUDAMQP_URL", "django://")
BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 1
BROKER_CONNECTION_MAX_RETRIES = None

CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = "json"
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ["json", "msgpack"]
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'

if BROKER_URL == "django://":
    INSTALLED_APPS += ("kombu.transport.django",)
```

Install the addon 
add the code to the seetings.py
enjoy!

https://drdaeman.github.io/heroku-djcelery-example/